How can we run the Jrerun command in SAS to run the LSF flow using the Flow_id?
I am trying to execute the Jrerun command by giving the Flow_id on SAS EG and SAS DI studio but the command is not running also it is not giving the error or warning.
I am trying to execute the below command in SAS.
x 'jrerun Flow_id';


Well, usually you would need to provide the full path to the jrerun executable, and the flow_id should be a numeric value, not the text "Flow_id"
